# Is it okay if i skip lunch or has any adverse effect on Fitness?

Tags: food, health

As per my daily schdule i do exercise around 1 hour daily which includes yoga and some basic workouts then eat a small bowl nuts then after ghis i have heavy breakfast which generally includes smoothies with cornflakes/museli or oats. Then in office i avoid lunch as it makes me little sleepy and out of focus. I drink 2-3 times green tea and in evening i have some snacks. Then after coming from office i have my dinner mostly focus on vegetables, grains and salad.
So my questions is if i skip my lunch daily, is bad for Fitness.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it will have an adverse affect on your fitness, but it will cause a dip in your energy levels, and make you more likely to reach for the wrong type of foods later, as you will be so hungry.   What foods have you tried at lunchtime that are making you sleepy?

Pasta, or anything that is too heavy is likely to have this affect.

Try A salad, a wrap or a bagel these shouldn't have the affect of making you sleepy, and will keep your energy levels more consistent throughout the day.

Comment: thanks for your advise. I am a vegetarian guy and as i am from india i used to eat indian food which is indian meal (vegetable gravy, rice, dal, indian bread). Can you please suggest others easy alternative which i can have by preparing by myself at home.

Comment: @himanshu - Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Indian food to advice with confidence, but I would of thought vegetables, dal, gravy, even rice and Indian bread would be fine providing it's a snack and not a full blown big meal.  Try reducing the rice and bread and see how that goes.  Maybe someone else would like to comment?

Comment: thanks.. i will try to avoid bread and rice and see show it goes.